# Пропадают обработчики события click при частичной перезагрузки блоков, как поправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Всем добрый день, спасибо, что заглянули!

Три дня бьюсь над задачкой, никак не могу решить, прошу помощи. Прошу прощения, что много текста, просто я не знаю, что здесь существенно, а что нет, поэтому написала все свои наблюдения. У меня на странице оформления заказа подключается внешний скрипт для выбора пункта самовывоза. Для его подключения указывается ссылка на скрипт, а в теле документа вот такая конструкция:

```
<div id="shiptor_widget" class="_shiptor_widget"></div>
```

и дописывается такая ссылка для того, чтобы виджет грузился только по клику на нее, а не сразу после загрузки документа:

```
<a href="#" class="pickpvz" data-role="shiptor_widget_show">Выбрать ПВЗ</a>
```

Так вот беда в чем: после загрузки страницы при клике на эту ссылку, виджет открывается, в браузере в `Event Listeners` я вижу, что на `click` по этой ссылке висит обработчик из подключенного внешнего скрипта виджета:
`click -> a.pickpvz` (*https://widget.shiptor.ru/embed/widget-pvz.js*), а как только я сменяю способ оплаты или доставки происходит частичная перезагрузка блоков (я не знаю как это реализовано, у меня модуль `simple` для opencart это делает) и после этой частичной перезагрузки, с вышеуказанной ссылки слетает этот обработчик на `click` и ссылка больше не открывает виджет ровно до тех пор, пока не перезагрузится вся страница. Так как я вообще ничего в этом не понимаю, то попробовала в момент частичной перезагрузки блоков заново подключать внешний скрипт, заново проставлять тег a и `div id="shiptor_widget"` в надежде, что этот обработчик будет снова навешиваться, но этого не происходит. Прошу подсказки, почему так происходит и как можно исправить?